# Refresh observable dictionary , listbox in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, observable

I bind  generic observable dictionary on listbox control in WPF app. I get every 5 sec  new fresh data as observable dictionary.

I would like refresh with this new dictionary listbox in wpf app.

My soulution is :

```
//this dic is bind on listbox
        private MyObservableDictionary<string, Friend> _friends;

//new data
        private MyObservableDictionary<string, Friend> _freshFriends;

....

//get data from server
            _freshFriends = _service.LoadFriends(Account);


            _friends.Clear();

//refresh dic
            foreach (var freshFriend in _freshFriends)
            {
                _friends.Add(freshFriend);
            }
```

My soulution works good, but exist any simple and nice way ? Thank for ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) (It makes anything "observable") so WPF knows when you directly assign to the friends list. In other words, make your friends list a property instead of a field and fire the PropertyChanged delegate on the `set` block :)

Hope that helps, read the link you will find more info there. Comment if you have any questions.

Comment: Yes, implementing INotifyPropertyChanged on _friends will alert the binding if you assign a whole new collection to that property.  The INotifyCollectionChanged only does it if elements within the collection change.

Comment: It observable dictionary so it must impelements         INotifyCollectionChanged and INotifyPropertyChanged. I would like reduce code on refresh dictionary.

Comment: @jminarik The Dictionary's INotifyCollectionChanged will only fire when you add/delete elements [It will also fire when elements are modified but only if they implement INotifyPropertyChanged] but not when you directly assign another dictionary to friends, In other words, friends was swapped, altho it didnt change. I know, WPF is weird, but its way easier than WinForms all the way.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have your own `MyObservableDictionary`, you could implement an `AddRange` function to it and just call it like this: `_friends.AddRange(_freshFriends);`  This could reduce code duplication if you wanted to add other collections as well.